# How to create an alphanumerical Hash string with fixed length?

Tags: macros

To identify an object in many different tabular environments, I want to create a pseudo random hash string with 5 digits (only capital letters). A continuously increasing number is no possibility in this case.

I'm searching for a macro which gives me a different hash string every time I call it. But the value must be the same independent of the compile cycle.

The result should look like within this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{HASH} & \textbf{Description} \\ \hline
A4X75 & This is the first Hash \\ \hline
7T0LE & This is the second Hash \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why specify 4 columns in a table which only has 2?

Comment: I adapted the MWE to be minimal without useless additional information :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use pseudorandom numbers elsewhere,

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\sys_gset_rand_seed:n { 0 }% or whatever

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hash}{}
 {
  \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:nn { 36 } { 1295 } } { 36 } % two digits
  \__pascals_hash_three:e { \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:n { 46655 } } { 36 } } % three digits
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__pascals_hash_three:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { 0 } #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__pascals_hash_three:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{HASH} & \textbf{Description} \\ \hline
\hash & This is the first Hash \\ \hline
\hash & This is the second Hash \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Fixing a seed will allow exact reproduction at every run.

[image]

You compute the probability of getting duplicates.

If you need to avoid duplicates because you have too many hashes compared to the number of digits, you lose expandability.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\sys_gset_rand_seed:n { 0 }% or whatever

\NewDocumentCommand{\hash}{}
 {
  \pascals_hash:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__pascals_hash_try_tl
\seq_new:N \g_pascals_hash_used_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pascals_hash:
 {
  % generate a tentative hash
  \tl_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_try_tl
   {
    \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:nn { 36 } { 1295 } } { 36 } % two digits
    \__pascals_hash_three:e { \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:n { 46655 } } { 36 } } % three digits 
   }
  % check for duplicate
  \seq_if_in:NVTF \g_pascals_hash_used_seq \l__pascals_hash_try_tl
   {% it's a duplicate, retry
    \pascals_hash:
   }
   {% not a duplicate
    \seq_gput_right:NV \g_pascals_hash_used_seq \l__pascals_hash_try_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__pascals_hash_try_tl
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__pascals_hash_three:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { 0 } #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__pascals_hash_three:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{HASH} & \textbf{Description} \\ \hline
\hash & This is the first Hash \\ \hline
\hash & This is the second Hash \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for this fast response! Exactly what I searched for!

Comment: I'm thinking about reducing my digits to 3 or 4 because lack of space. So the probability to create duplicates will increase. Is there an easy way to check for duplicates and in case create a new one? Maybe encapsulated within the hash macro?

Comment: @PascalS Added the code with the check for duplicates

Comment: Seems to be what I'm searching for, but at [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) I got errors. It's not compileable.

Comment: When `\int_rand:n` returns 7 (for example) then you doesn't get three digits.

Comment: @wipet You're right. I'll fix.

Comment: @PascalS The check for duplicates is slow. I tried generating 10000 of them and got no duplicate. So I believe you can quite safely use the “nonchecking” version.

Comment: Okay got it! One last thing, I will add this hash calculation in this [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709852/104358). In this example the hash function will be called twice, once for the `\pgfplotstable` entry and once for the graphical `\pic label`. But in case, this should be the same value. So is it possible just to call the `\hash` routine only every second call or give a parameter to the function if a new one should be generated or the old value should be taken?

Comment: @PascalS Sorry, but I don't really get it. Can you please open a new question with the details?

Comment: I gave my best to describe it in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709902/derive-table-data-and-tikz-lable-from-the-same-data-source.) question now :)

Answer (score 3):

I show what to do with OpTeX. We have no already prepared macro like `\_int_to_Base`, so we have to use LauTeX primitives `\Uchar`, `\uniformdeviate` and we generate six digits in the loop. The probability of the occurrence of a digit in the string is set to 1/3.

```
\setrandomseed 100 % radom generator initialized, the same for all compilation
\def\randomchar#1#2{\Uchar\numexpr`#1+\uniformdeviate\numexpr`#2-`#1\relax\relax}
\def\randomhash{%
    \fornum 1..6 \do
        {\ifnum\uniformdeviate3 >1 \randomchar 09\else \randomchar AZ\fi}%
}
\def\createhash{\edef\hash{\randomhash}%
   \ifcsname hash:\hash \endcsname \ea\createrandomhash % the hash is already used
   \else \sxdef{hash:\hash}{}\hash \fi
} 

\table{|(\tt)c|c|}{\crl
   \bf HASH    & \bf Description \crl
   \createhash & This is the first Hash \crl
   \createhash & This is the second Hash \crl
}

\bye
```